# How do you “unpurchase” an in-app purchase in the iOS sandbox?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

When testing my implementation of in-app purchases, I'd like to test the implementations of users who have not bought the IAP and users who have. Is there a way to do this without creating multiple users?

Comment: No, you need to create another test account

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. What you can do, though, is create a sandbox tester account with an invalid email address because these accounts don't need to be validated. So you can just create a bunch of accounts with non-working emails i.e. test1@fakeaddress.com, test2@fakeaddress.com etc.

Comment: Doesnt it need to be a valid apple ID?

Comment: No, you don't need to confirm the account so you can put anything you want.